Properties of superharmonic functions on compact subsets
I'm currently trying to prove the following -
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and $u \in C^2(\Omega)$ is a superharmonic function in $\Omega$, namely $-\Delta u(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Omega$.
a) Prove that for any compact subset $K \subset \Omega$ and any $x \in K$, we have
$$u(x) \geq \text{inf}_{\Omega / K} u.$$
b) Use result in (a) to prove that for any $x \in \Omega$, we have
$$ u(x) \geq \text{inf}_{\partial \Omega} u.$$
Am I correct to assume that I should start with some variation of the maximum principle for superharmonic functions to prove part a)? For the second one, I'm thinking of either arguing with some sort of compact exhaustion of $\Omega$ or creating a path with the compact subsets all the way to the boundary, if that makes sense.
EDIT:
So here's what I got so far. It's probably simpler to just assume the minimum principle for superharmonic functions and go from there, i.e.,
let $u$ be a superharmonic function ($-\Delta u(x) \geq 0$), then it satisfies the minimum principle -
$$\displaystyle\min_{\overline{\Omega}}u = \displaystyle\min_{\partial{\Omega}}u.$$
From this we can directly see that b) holds since this proves a stronger statement. And from b) I think a) follows somewhat directly but I'm not too sure on the finer points of the argument?
Taking a non-empty compact subset $K$ and some $x \in K$, then we have that $u(x) \geq \displaystyle\inf_{\partial{\Omega}}u$ from a) but again, I'm unsure how to show rigorously that it will also be greater than $\displaystyle\inf_{\Omega / K}u$
